# Promised Streaming to Base64 not concatenating full response

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, base64, node-streams

I'm trying to download a potentially large file by streaming. It must be accumulated into memory because the API I'm using requires a base64 upload. However, I'm thinking a stream might still be necessary because the implementation would be in a web server and I don't want to block the event loop. Any ideas on why this code might not be working? It seems like the chunks aren't being concatenated because I'm getting only the first piece of the response body when I debug.

```
import { Transform } from "stream";
import axios from "axios";
import fs from "fs/promises";

class Base64EncodeStream extends Transform {
  private completePromise: Promise<string>;

  constructor() {
    super({
      transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
        this.push(chunk.toString("base64"));
        callback();
      },
    });

    this.completePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let data = "";

      this.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      this.on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

      this.on("end", () => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }

  promise() {
    return this.completePromise;
  }
}

async function main() {
  const res = await axios({
    url: "https://www.google.com",
    method: "get",
    responseType: "stream",
  });

  const base64EncodeStream = new Base64EncodeStream();

  res.data.pipe(base64EncodeStream);

  const base64Encoded = await base64EncodeStream.promise();

  await fs.writeFile("out.txt", base64Encoded, "utf8");
}

main();
```

Comment: `chunk.toString("base64")` does not work, base64 does require padding and you want to do that only once not for every chunk

Comment: Why not implement a proper transform stream and *stream* the result to the file? You should not need that `completePromise`.

Comment: @Bergi My thinking is that because I'm going to use the encoded file right after the download, I can just keep the file in memory instead of writing to the file system which is relatively slow

Comment: The Promise would allow me to await the downloading and encoding step

Comment: You say you want to upload the file to somewhere. Sure, why write it to the file system? Just use the transformed stream for the upload.

Comment: Because the API requires a JSON body like so: `{ file_name: str, file_body: <base64_encoded> }`